# Buttons are shifted away from the line

Tags: css, html, web

I am making a website currently, and when I created a row of buttons a few of them were slightly shifted from the line.

My website: *(unfortunately just a template so I can't really send you the link)*
[image]

Code:*(HTML)*

[image]

Code:*(CSS)*

[image]

It seems weird to me as the buttons are set 100% of the height of their container, so technically they aren't suppose to get out of it anyway. I tried messing with the width and height of the container, but nothing seems to work. Perhaps I am missing something simple.

If any other parts of the stylesheet needed I can post it.

I'm not sure if everyone got my problem. I'm saying that it's pretty weird that while the button's height is set *100%*, a few of the buttons still manage to move slightly down from the majority of buttons.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a fiddle? easier to ask, easier to answer ;-)

Comment: @Yoeri do you mean like a link to the code?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is your margin.

The GameBtn puts a margin on all sides, whereas the MenuBtn sets a margin to the left only. This will jack things up.

Not sure, however, why you position the container element absolute. But, that may be another discussion. Also, you have a top AND a margin-top property set in the container element. You can remove one of those. If you meant to center the container element, you can just position it relative and set the margin to margin: 65px auto 0;

Comment: Margin doesn't seem to be the problem. Could it be possible that the content inside the buttons is causing the shift?

Comment: Still, margin: -2.5px does nothing. And, instead of applying a width to your buttons, apply left and right padding. That way the button grows with the content length of the button name.